# How do i use idealGraphVisualizer?

Tags: jvm

I build the idealgraphVisualizer in openjdk9 using "ant build" command. Also I generated a file.xml by running my java file. After this, how can i see  file.xml using the visualizer. I am running all these in a Linux system

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IdealGraphVisualizer is made on top of NetBeans platform. The easiest way to run it is to open the project in NetBeans and to build and run it from IDE.
After the IGV main windows appears, choose *File -> Open...* from the menu.